# Gatsby starter cannot be built

Tags: build, gatsby

I'm using Gatsby v2.18.10 and wanted to try out some cool looking starters (https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/hasura/gatsby-gitbook-starter/), but after I created a new project with the starter I couldn't build the project. I could start in on developer mode, but had this error while trying to run "gatsby build":

```
Warning: App: Error boundaries should implement getDerivedStateFromError(). In that method, return a state update to display an error message or fallback UI.
```

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'activities' of undefined at getGlobalStatus`

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried out other starters still, this issue occurred with only this starter.

I solved the problem with upgrading my gatsby version, now it works with this one too.